# How to update the array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
   import java.util.Random;
   import java.lang.Object;
   import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
  int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int rnd = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
int a = rnd;
TA1.setText("\n Random interger: " + a); //jTextArea (im using netbeans to build the gui by using the swing controls in the pallete)
for (int i: array) 
{
    System.out.print(" " + i);
}
switch (a) {
    case 1:
        TA1.append("Hello1");
        array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, 1);
        for (int i: array) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        TA1.append("Hello2");
        array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, 2);
        for (int i: array) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        TA1.append("Hello3");
        array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, 3);
        for (int i: array) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        TA1.append("Hello4");
        array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, 4);
        for (int i: array) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        TA1.append("Hello1");
        array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, 5);
        for (int i: array) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
        }
        break;
    case 6:
        TA1.append("Hello6");
        array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, 6);
        for (int i: array) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
        }
        break;
    case 7:
        TA1.append("Hello7");
        array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, 7);
        for (int i: array) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
        }
        break;
    case 8:
        TA1.append("Hello8");
        array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, 8);
        for (int i: array) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
        }
        break;
    case 9:
        TA1.append("Hello9");
        array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, 9);
        for (int i: array) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
        }
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("error");
        break;
}
```

}

I wrote this code to update array elements, but every time I click on the button for which this the code, the array gets initialised to the original values that were declared. I want the array to be updated i.e., each time when an element is removed, the change should be visible when I click on the button the next time.
I figured why the problem was happening but i have no idea how to solve it other than storing the numbers in a DB. I want something thats a little more efficient

Comment: sorry, I didn't get what u said

Comment: What's `ArrayUtils`? Please provide [mcve]

Comment: `int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};` you are declaring your array in the "method", so your array would always be re-initialized. if you want to preserve the state, make your array an instance variable of the class, or put it in some external storage like a file or DB if you want it to be preserved everytime you launch your program.

Comment: i need a solution quickly, i have to submit this on moday

Comment: Telling us you need this quickly makes it sound like we are fast food chefs, which we're not.

Comment: I downvoted because requests for fast answers are unwelcome here.

Comment: Please provide the complete class code

Comment: fast answers are not welcome anywhere i know that, but its kinda urgent, so i need ur help and im not good in programming. Im doing this with half baked knowledge. So pls instead of posting unhelpful comments i would appreciate it if u can help me solve my problem.

Comment: That was meant as helpful, I am sorry that you didn’t perceive it that way. It takes a bit to learn to use Stack Overflow the best way, we’ve all had to learn, and I was trying to guide you in that process. [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: i have pasted the complete code now. Also -dubes thnx for suggesting DB method, but wont that complicate the task. I don't really know what u meant by instance variable of a class. I have been using NetBeans without having learnt java properly

Comment: @DhruvSinha Then I suggest that you also format it properly, because two other people have done it for you before and you broke it yet again.

Comment: this is the first time im using stackoverflow, I don't really know how this works

Comment: can anybody help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the complete code, but I guess that's because of this line:

```
 int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

Always this block of code is executed, the array is initialized again. You need to manage the state of this array properly after initialization.